# Comparing laravel collections

Tags: laravel, compare, laravel-collection

I have two collections: "Instructions" and "Known". Basically I am taking a new set of "Instructions" and checking whether anything is different to what is "Known".

So, the quantity is not massive. I retrieve the info:

```
$Instructions = Instruction::all();
$Knowns = Known::all();
```

Now, I'm looking for the differences, and I've tried each of these three methods:

```
$IssuesFound = $Instructions->diff($Knowns); 
$IssuesFound = $Instructions->diffKeys($Knowns); 
$IssuesFound = $Instructions->diffAssoc($Knowns);
```

The thing is, an "Instruction" or "Known" is an item with 17 attributes, and anyone of those attributes can be different. I want to compare the attributes of an "Instruction" with the matching attribute of a "Known". (Both items have the same keys, bot items have a `Reference` attribute to act as a unique identifier.

What I'm finding is that theese methods give me the item that is different, but doesn't tell me which individual attributes are the mismatch.

```
foreach ($IssuesFound as $issue)
    {
        dd($issue);
    }
```

So a method like `$IssuesFound = $Instructions->diffKeys($Knowns);` will come up with item xxx being different, but I can't see how to find out which attribute of the item it is that is different. Not unless I start nesting loops and iterating through all the attributes - which I'm trying to avoid.

How do I do it?

Thanks in advance. (Laravel 5.6)

Answer (score 0):

Straight from laravel docs, diffAssoc will return what you are asking:

```
$collection = collect([
    'color' => 'orange',
    'type' => 'fruit',
    'remain' => 6
]);

$diff = $collection->diffAssoc([
    'color' => 'yellow',
    'type' => 'fruit',
    'remain' => 3,
    'used' => 6
]);

$diff->all();

// ['color' => 'orange', 'remain' => 6]
```

You get the attribute from the FIRST collection that is different on the SECOND collection, therefore if you get 3 attributes when calling `$diff->all()` you will know WHICH attributes ARE DIFFERENT, so you could access them or do whatever you want to, if you post more specific results of what you are getting and what you are trying we can help, but I think you are just not thinking how to use these methods

Comment: I think the problem is that my collection is two levels deep. An "Instruction" or a "Known" has 17 Attributes. But my "Instructions" is a collection of "Intruction" - if that makes sense. I.m seeing diffAssoc comparing at the higher level, not the deeper level.